# How can one evaluate the expression: $\nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$, such that $i,j = x,y,z$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm familiar with the Laplacian, but I'm unsure how to evaluate

$\nabla_{i}\nabla_{j}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$, such that $i,j = x,y,z$,

with this notation.

This is my attempt, assuming

$r=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{1/2}$.

Taking $j$ to be $x$, for example, my first step would then be

$\nabla_{j}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{-1/2}\right]=-\frac{x}{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{3/2}}{\bf x}$

I'm basically assuming I just take the gradient in the $x$.

But then if I take $i$ to be $y$, for example, I take the divergence of that answer and have

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(0\,{\bf y})=0$

for the final answer because the first step gave me a vector in the ${\bf x}$ direction only?

Comment: I suppose that $\nabla$ just means the partial derivatives $\partial$, right?

Comment: @Someone I think they are saying $\nabla _i$ is the $i$th component of $\nabla$ for example $\nabla _x=\hat x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$

Comment: @D.Jones just because a vector points in the x direction doesn't mean it can't vary with y

Comment: @Aaron Stevens yes, but I was assuming that I first take the gradient in 'x' only (giving a vector in 'x'), then take the divergence in 'y' only. The first step leaves me with no component in 'y'

Comment: Are you taking the divergence or just the partial derivative with respect to y? I think your use of notation is throwing me off. The partial derivative with respect to y of the first step isn't 0, whether or not it is part of a divergence calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this (assuming $r \ne 0$) :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\partial_i \, r^{-1} = -\, \frac{1}{r^2} \, \partial_i \, r = -\, \frac{x_i}{r^3}.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{align}
\partial_j \, \partial_i \, r^{-1} &= -\, \partial_j \Big( \, \frac{x_i}{r^3} \, \Big) \\[12pt]
&= \frac{3}{r^5} \, x_j \, x_i - \frac{1}{r^3} \, \delta_{ij}. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Actually, there's a Dirac delta entering that expression, to include the case $r = 0$, but this is another subject.

Notice that if you contract the indices $i$ and $j$, then you get the Laplacian :
\begin{align}
\nabla^2 \, r^{-1} \equiv \partial_i \, \partial_i \, r^{-1} &= \frac{3}{r^5} \, x_i \, x_i - \frac{1}{r^3} \, \delta_{ii} \\[12pt]
&\equiv \frac{3}{r^5} \, r^2 - \frac{1}{r^3} \, 3 = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Thank you. This is about what I expected to see, recognizing that there should be a Dirac delta issue. I am just unsure how you arrived at (2). Working things out now

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I have the first term, but not the Kronecker delta term that follows. It might just be that I didn't simplify my solution enough.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I distributed and got the same answer, which appears to match the explicit solution I obtain the long, ugly way. Thanks so much!